# How to set Windows Terminal (UWP) as an external terminal for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-terminal

The title mostly says it all about the question.
I want to set the newest Microsoft's Windows Terminal as an external terminal in Visual Studio Code.

I found the WT's executable in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_0.4.2382.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsTerminal.exe`. Then I entered the path into VSC in the `terminal.external.windowsExec`. Then tried to run my program, but VSC showed a pop-up which says "Could not find "C:\Program". Check whether the path is written right an try again."
Also I have tried to use a shortcut (literally dragged the WT tile from Start to my desktop folder), then entered its path into the setting, but it just opens the app without starting the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are essentially asking VS Code to `Run...` a program via the `Ctrl + Shift + C` command.

Per the tip [here](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/08/how-to-open-windows-terminal-from-command-prompt-or-run/), you can achieve what you are looking for by simply entering:

`wt`

...into the `terminal.external.windowsExec` section.

Answer (score 3):

WT now supports the "-d" parameter to open itself in a given directory: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/4023

But VSCODE does not allow to pass arguments to an external terminal: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58086

The workaround for this is to create a batch script somewhere called **wt.bat** containing:

```
@start wt.exe -d "."
@exit
```

And put it on vscode *Terminal>External: Windows Exec* setting.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be handling the space in the filename correctly. Try surrounding the pathname in quotes like this: `"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_0.4.2382.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsTerminal.exe"`

Answer (score 1):

I can open it with this configuration

```
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "wt.exe"
```

---

My windows terminal version is 1.11.2921.0

Then I found that Windows terminal is actually wt.exe

It's in a path like this `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\************\wt.exe`

Then, I add the above 'wt.exe' to the vscode configuration file

Comment: If you still can't, you can directly use the absolute path, for example:

```"terminal.external.windowsExec":"C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\************\\wt.exe",
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the "Windows Terminal", as external terminal, does not launch in the workspace directory ([issue 90734](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90734))

> 1. Set terminal.external.windowsExec to wt
> 2. Run "Open New External Terminal" from the command palette
>
> A new instance of Windows Terminal opens, **but with the default directory, instead of `${workspaceFolder}`**.

So while the [Windows Terminal Preview v0.9 Release](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-v0-9-release/) allows a starting directory to be specified with `-d <starting dir>`, it would  not work with VSCode up to 1.44 (March 2020).

This should be fixed with VSCode 1.45 (April 2020): [PR 90773](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/90773).